# Empty ResultSet still evaluating to true, JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I wrote a simple check method to check whether data exists in a MySQL db for a given string id:

```
    public boolean checkForData(String etfSymbol){
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(CHECK_FOR_DATA);
            statement.setString(1, etfSymbol);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!result.isBeforeFirst()){
                System.out.println("No data currently in database for this ETF");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Data already exists in database for this ETF");
    return true;
}
```

Query:

```
    final String CHECK_FOR_DATA = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM basic_etf_data WHERE etf_name = (?)"
```

I can confirm with MySQL workbench that no data is in the table for the id that I am requesting (no data at all actually) yet the condition is evaluating to true.
Here's the debug output for the ResultSet:

[image: first-half]
[image: second-half]

At first, "InvalidRowReason" led me to believe that it was evaluating to true because the index is in fact before the first, but the docs for isBeforeFirst() state:

> true if the cursor is before the first row; **false if** the cursor is at any other position or **the result set contains no rows**

I then expanded the rowData and found that the size was equal to 1:

[image: row data]

I have no idea how this can be as I can confirm that no rows or even any data exist in the table. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are making a COUNT in SQL and COUNT has always a result(a row), in your case 0. Anyway, I probably would write your query as

```
SELECT * FROM basic_etf_data WHERE etf_name = ? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This did the trick. My db contains a lot of data and I read the COUNT(*) was the smarter option over *. However, I just now read the docs on COUNT and found that it DOES NOT count nulls. This is why InvalidRowReason was "Before start of result set." and was legitimately returning true. Just debugged again and InvalidRowReason is now "Illegal operation on empty result set." and returns false as it should. THE NULLS!